# listar para cada barrio la cadena con mayor numero de locales

Tags: sql-server, sql, subconsultas

el ejercicio que  intente resolver es el siguiente :listar para cada barrio la cadena con mayor numero de locales

las tablas utilizadas son las siguientes :

```
create table cadena(
IdCadena int primary key not null,
Nombre varchar(50),
FecInicioActividad date ) 

create table barrio(
IdBarrio int primary key not null,
Nombre varchar(50)
)
create table locales(
IdCadena int not null,
NroLocal int not null,
IdBarrio int not null,
CapMaxima int,
FecUltimaInspeccion date,
constraint PKLOCAL primary key(IdCadena ,NroLocal,IdBarrio),
constraint FKCADENA foreign key (IdCadena) references cadena(IdCadena) on 
delete cascade,
constraint FKBARRIO foreign key (IdBarrio) references barrio(IdBarrio) on 
delete cascade
)
```

lo que hice hasta el momento y no funciono porque me devuelve el barrio la cadena con el nro de locales maximo pero no me devuelve para cada barrio sino solamente el que posee el maximo  total.

```
create view localescadenabarrio as (
select l.IdBarrio as barrio ,l.IdCadena as cadena, COUNT(l.NroLocal) as 
cantlocales
from locales l
group by l.IdBarrio, l.IdCadena
)

select lc.barrio,lc.cadena 
from localescadenabarrio lc
where lc.cantlocales = ( select MAX(lc2.cantlocales)
                            from localescadenabarrio lc2)
group by lc.barrio,lc.cadena
```

Answer (score 0):

Puede que se esta la query que buscas?:

```
select b.IdCadena, 
       b.idBarrio, 
       loc.max_local 
from locales b join (
    select MAX(loc.NroLocal) max_local, 
           loc.idCadena 
   from locales loc 
   group by loc.idCadena
) loc on    b.IdCadena = loc.IdCadena;
```